# How to make dynamic looping counter when using condition

Tags: php

I have a total data and I want to loop a number of data I had at the beginning. Only in the data enabling conditions whereby if the conditions are met then it will pass count counter and will be reduced. In sample case,

I need 10 data from loop

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        if($i == '8') {
                echo "DATA PASSED : ".$i."<br>";
                $i-1;
        } else {
                echo "SUCCESS : ".$i."<br>";
        }
}
```

Result

```
SUCCESS : 1
SUCCESS : 2
SUCCESS : 3
SUCCESS : 4
SUCCESS : 5
SUCCESS : 6
SUCCESS : 7
DATA PASSED  : 8
SUCCESS : 9
SUCCESS : 10
```

In In the case above, the result of looping my code is not right. No reductions resulting from the total looping.

The data should be 10. If I can see, I only get 9 data because the data of the 8th should be skipped.

How should I correct code and can generate

```
SUCCESS : 1
SUCCESS : 2
SUCCESS : 3
SUCCESS : 4
SUCCESS : 5
SUCCESS : 6
SUCCESS : 7
DATA PASSED  : 8
SUCCESS : 9
SUCCESS : 10
SUCCESS : 11
```

Where the result is 10 data. Thanks

Comment: it's very clear if u wants to skip 8 out of 10 output will contain 9 data, can u explain more ur scenario?

Comment: Hi @GoldunoSupport it will contain 9 data, but I still need 10 data

Comment: please have a look on answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do while` or a `while` loop should suit your case better. I am not a php expert, but this should work. More info on looping in php can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp).

```
$counter = 1; 
$i= 0; // it should be start with 0

while($counter <= 10) {
    $i++;
    if($i == '8') {
            echo "DATA PASSED : ".$i."<br>";
    } else {
            echo "SUCCESS : ".$i."<br>";
            $counter++; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code

```
 $data_passed =false;
    for ($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            if($i == '8') {
                    echo "DATA PASSED : ".$i."<br>";
                    echo "SUCCESS : ".($i+1)."<br>";
                    $data_passed = true;
            } else{
            echo "SUCCESS : ".($data_passed?$i+1:$i)."<br>";
            } 
    }
```

Hope you understood the code